# prototype: Element.remove.bind(foo) doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, bind

I have this snippet:

```
self.puff({duration: 0, queue: 'end',
        afterFinish: Element.remove.bindAsEventListener(self)
    });
```

Self is an element; it is supposed to remove an element from document when all effects on it are completed.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work, failing with "element.parentNode is undefined".
If I replace `Element.remove.bindAsEventListener(self)` with `function() { self.remove(); }` then it would. I've tried just bind() with the same results.

The question is: why doesn't it work, and how should I use bind()?

Bonus points for showing an easier way to remove an element after all effects on it are done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
self.puff({duration: 0, queue: 'end',
    afterFinish: function () { self.remove(); }
});
```

What's wrong with this way of putting it? You even suggest it yourself. In any case, you don't need to bind it as an event listener, since it is only a Prototype syntatic sugar version of bind to ensure that the first parameter to the function is always the event-object. Since afterFinish is not a browser event, it is unnecessary.

Finally, you are binding the incorrect function. You should bind the method instance of *self*:

```
self.puff({duration: 0, queue: 'end',
    afterFinish: self.remove.bind(self)
});
```

Comment: Oh!
I guess I have to use Element.remove.curry() not bind()
Either way, I think I'll stay with `function () { self.remove(); }`

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use:

```
function(){ self.remove(); }
```

This is actually more readable.

Comment: I did it, yet I want to know why bind() fails
`Element.remove.bind(self)` is nicer IMO, if only it worked.